# Wrong result in string comparision in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am troubled with the string comparison query in linq. I want statusid for which statustype as my desired string say "Draft". Below is the query

```
var result = (from Roaster_RequestStatus status in statuses
                        where status.StatusName.Equals("Draft")
                        select status).ToList<Roaster_RequestStatus>();
```

But `result` showing count of 0 even my list `statuses` contains `StatusName` as "Draft"
also i tried below query which provides value 0 for `i`.

```
var i = (from Roaster_RequestStatus status in statuses
                         where status.StatusName.Equals("Draft")
                         select status.StatusID).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
```

Please help if there is any syntax or logical error is present in the code

Comment: Try trimming the status name, there may be leading or trailing spaces. Try `status.StatusName.Trim().Equals("Draft")`, also make sure the case is same for both. You can try. `status.StatusName.Equals("Draft",StringComparison.StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Can you show us sample data and your class definition?

Comment: Try changing .Equals("Draft"), to .Contains("Draft").

Comment: is this LinqToObjects? Or are you using another provider such as LinqToEntities?

Comment: @eraj, then you definitely have something other than "Draft" in your statusName

Comment: I do not found any spaces or any character in data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work :-

```
var result = (from Roaster_RequestStatus status in statuses
                        where status.StatusName.Contains("Draft")
                        select status).ToList<Roaster_RequestStatus>();
```